# progress indicator inside an alertdialog in android

Tags: android

Need a similar screen in android i.e putting an progress indicator inside an alert view.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is ANDROID ? :P

Comment: this not android? its iPhone!!!!! but i need this kind of indicator in android

Answer (score 1):

Android has `ProgressDialog` which can do pretty much the same thing, display a dialog, show a title and a message, and also show an indeterminate progress indicator, but it will look a bit different than in your screenshot.

However, the use of `ProgressDialog` to indicate loading or indeterminate progress is not adviced by Android documentation:

> **Avoid ProgressDialog**
>   Android includes another dialog class called ProgressDialog that shows a dialog with a progress bar. However, if
>   you need to indicate loading or indeterminate progress, you should
>   instead follow the design guidelines for [Progress & Activity](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html) and use a
>   ProgressBar in your layout.

So, [you will need to define your custom dialog.](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/creating-and-displaying-a-custom-dialog-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a layout xml for the dialog content.
2. Inflate it to a view.
3. Call ALertDialog.setView with your view

Answer (score 0):

```
   private static final int DIALOG_PROGRESS = 4;
  private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private int mProgress;
        private Handler mProgressHandler;

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_PROGRESS:
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
                mProgressDialog.setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("R.string.select_dialog");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setMax(MAX_PROGRESS);
                mProgressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                        "R.string.alert_dialog_hide", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked Yes so do some stuff */
                    }
                });
                mProgressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                        "R.string.alert_dialog_cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
                    }
                });
                return mProgressDialog;
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Initialization of the Activity after it is first created.  Must at least
         * call {@link android.app.Activity#setContentView(int)} to
         * describe what is to be displayed in the screen.
         */
        @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
            mProgressHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    if (mProgress >= MAX_PROGRESS) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        mProgress++;
                        mProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                        mProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

[Refrence from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/DialogwithProgress.htm) you should handle by Handler method and get it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Create `CustomAlertDialog` by inflating a view from layout.

Layout should be in `RelativeLayout`, so that you can place `ProgessDialog` center of that layout by giving property as `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` and `CENTER_VERTICAL`.

Refer: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout)